# Can't get Sinatra Flash Gem to work

Tags: ruby, sinatra, alert

I am trying to get a flash notice to appear after a successful submission of a form. In Rails I would use something like this in the controller:

```
:notice => "Youve submitted the form"
```

I came across the [Sinatra flash](https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash) gem and would like to display a flash message after a redirect. I installed the gem and setup like so:

myapp.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/flash'
enable :sessions

#form config
 )}
redirect '/success' # this is the hook after my form submission
end

get('/success') do
 flash[:success] = "Thanks for your email. I'll be in touch soon."
 erb :index 
end
```

All that happens is that I am redirected to the index page with no flash message. Looking at the docs this is all I can see that I need to do. Does anyone see anything different?

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you added appropriate code in your index.* view? something like

= flash

Comment: could you expand on that a litte please, not quite sure what you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I moved my flash notice to before the redirect so it could save the message:

```
flash[:notice] = "Thanks for your email. I'll be in touch soon."
redirect '/success'

get('/success') do
 erb :index 
end
```

Then, in my view, I placed this at the top for now:

```
<div id='flash' class='notice'>
 <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
 <%= flash[:notice] %>
</div>
```

It needs some styling but works. If anyone has a better solution then please share.

Comment: You can also use the [styled_flash](https://github.com/SFEley/sinatra-flash#styled_flash) helper within your views to display the flash message.